# Trigger action if latest serviceworker is activated (no updatefound)

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I would like to detect if there is NO update for my service worker and trigger some action in my app.js. Basically detect if the latest version of my serviceworker is activated and no update is available.

I have a splash screen on page load saying "checking for updates", which then gives me time to install the new service worker if one is avaiable.

Once the latest version is running, I would like to hide my splash screen and show the actual app content.

I tried several attempts but it does not seem to work. The issues is, that I update my serviceworker automatically, which refreshes the page and shows me the splash screen again - but I can't find the right approach to detect whether the latest service worker version is already installed and hide my splash screen.

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {

  window.addEventListener("load", () => {

    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register("./service-worker.js")
      .then((reg) => {
        console.log("Service worker registered:", reg);

        reg.addEventListener('updatefound', () => {
            // do stuff if there is an update
            // eg. reg.update() -> refreshes pages
        });

        //DESIRED: do stuff here if there is NO update found
        
      })
      .catch((err) =>
        console.error("Service worker registration failed:", err)
      );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the `active` property:

```js
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register("./service-worker.js")
      .then((reg) => {
        console.log("Service worker registered:", reg);

        reg.addEventListener("updatefound", () => {
          // do stuff if there is an update
          // eg. reg.update() -> refreshes pages
        });

        if (reg.active) {
          // Latest version active
          hideSplashScreen();
        } else {
          reg.addEventListener("statechange", () => {
            if (reg.active) {
              hideSplashScreen();
            }
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) =>
        console.error("Service worker registration failed:", err)
      );
  });
}

function hideSplashScreen() {
  // TODO: hide splash screen code
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work. the if condition fires always, and the else condition only after a new worker was installed. I need an event that fires only if no NEW worker was installed at all. I edited my question to point that out more accurate